# How to add a sliding div to these CSS Message Bubbles?

Tags: html, css

new to webdev so bear with me. I am developing a prototype of a Messaging Application, I have most of the basics worked out and I'm trying to add the little touches to make it feel nicer to use. I'm trying to make it so that when an individual message is hovered over, the time that message was sent will slide out from the message.

Here is my code at the moment: http://codepen.io/RBrNx/pen/GNzOWr
(Note: Click on "Toni" again and his message will appear, small bug. You can also send messages from the text box).

Now here are some images showing what I mean:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ksGF.jpg

Ideally I think the 2nd one would look better.

I tried to implement it by adding a `span` inside the bubble like so:

```
<div class="bubble you">Test Message<span class="hover-time">13.45</span></div>

.hover-time{
   position: relative;
   left: 60px;
}
```

But that made the inside of the bubble stretch to account for the Span.

How can this be done?

**EDIT: Thanks to Antidecaf I managed to get the left side working and figured out the right hand side as well. Here is the CSS I added**:

```
.container .right .bubble.you .hover-time {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 110%;
    color: #999;
    width: 100px;
}

.container .right .bubble.me .hover-time {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 90%;
    color: #999;
    width: 100px;
}
```

These deal with the left hand messages (from the person you are messaging) and the right hand messages (from me). I also added:

```
.container .right .bubble.you:hover .hover-time{
    display: inline-block;
}
.container .right .bubble.me:hover .hover-time{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

So that the hover-time span is shown on hover.

Comment: position: absolute;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the markup you suggested by positioning `.hover-time` relative to `.bubble`. To do this, add `position: relative` to .bubble and `position: absolute` to .hover-time. [Here's some more info on the technique](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/).

```
<div class="bubble you"><span class="hover-time">13.45</span>Test Message</div>
```

CSS for positioning timestamp to the right:

```
.bubble {
    position: relative;
}

.hover-time {
    position: absolute;
    left: 110%;
    color: #999;
}
```

Same approach goes for positioning it to the left, but in this case you'll need to add a bit of margin to the bubble in order to free up space for the timestamp:

```
.bubble {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.hover-time {
    position: absolute;
    left: -50px;
    color: #999;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked for the left hand side, but you pointed me in the right direction to get the right hand side working as well! I've updated my post with the CSS I added.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.hover-time {
  position: relative;
  left: 60px;
  display: none;
}

.bubble:hover .hover-time {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
}
</style>
<div class="bubble you">Test Message <span class="hover-time">13.45</span></div>
```

Works for me. You'll probably want to spice it up a little with some transform or other fancy anim stuff.

EDIT: Perhaps you meant like so:

```
<style>
.bubble {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 300px;
}

.hover-time {
  float: right;
  display: none;
}

.bubble:hover .hover-time {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
}
</style>
<div class="bubble you">Test Message <span class="hover-time">13.45</span></div>
```

Border and width just to have a visual guide.

Comment: Thanks for your help. That mostly works but you can see that the inside of the bubble expands to account for the Span, even though the span is getting displayed on the outside.

Comment: No I mean exactly the way it looks in the images I posted. Where the time is literally 'floating' outside of the right or left hand side of the speech bubble.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but are you styling the DIV as the speech bubble, then taking the span inside the div and telling it 'but not you buddy, you are special'?

If so, isn't it cleaner and less headaches to put your text message in a span also, styling the span as text bubble, and keeping the div as an invisible structural element?

Comment: Hmm I think I see what you mean. So I should change the text to a Span, create a new Div around the Span which is invisible and then I can add another Span to the Div which will be the message time?

Comment: Seems convoluted, but maybe I'm not understanding your issue properly. I'd put the time in one span, the text in another, make the div invisible and 100% width, and then style the spans as needed. Seems the least code bloat.